# Tensorflow.js constant retraining

Tags: server-side, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow.js

I have a application were we gather and classify images triggered by motion detection. We have a model trained on a lot of images that works OK. I have converted it to TF.js format and are able to make predictions in the browser, so far so good.

However we have cameras on a lot of different locations and the lighting and surroundings vary on each location whereas and we also put up new cameras each year. So we would need to retrain the model often and I am also afraid that the model will be to generic and not so accurate on each specific location.

All data we gather from the motion detection is uploaded to our server and we use a web interface to classify all the images as "false positive, positive etc" and store everything in a MYSQL database.

The best solution I think would to have a generic model trained on a lot of data. This model would be implemented on each each specific location. And while we manually interpret each image as we normally would do we would relearn the generic model so that it will be specific to each location.

To solve this we have to serve the models on our server our on some host and be able to write to the model since we are a lot of different people interpreting the data on different browsers and computers.

Would it be possible and a good solution? I would love some input before I invest more time in to this. I haven't found a whole lot of information about, serving writable models and reinforcement learning on tensorflow.js

So 
I was wondering if it is possible to serve tensoflow.js on our server that was trained on our data. But for every manual intepretation the model would "relearn" with the new image.